# Convergent and divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

So the Question is the following :
Indicate whether the following statements are true or false. Prove the statement, if any
is true, or give a counterexample if it is a false statement.

a) Each monotone increasing sequence converges to $\infty$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

b) If (an) is not limited then follows an $\rightarrow \infty$ or an $\rightarrow -\infty$

So I'm really bad at mathematics and I'm having troubles understanding this, so if you answer please write the reasoning because I'm really really bad at this

Please, someone, help me

And Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Consider (a) $1-\frac1n$  (b) $(-1)^n$.

Comment: a) false, b) false. I am really bad at explaining.

Comment: By "not limited" do you mean "not bounded", or simply that a limit does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should indicate what you have tried - this site is not going to do your homework for you.

Secondly you need to check the questions you are asking.

(a) What does converge to $\infty$ mean? $\infty$ is not a number. Perhaps you mean diverges / does not converge?

To answer the question why not consider the graphs of some of the inverse trigonometric functions - one of these will show you the correct result.

(b) What do you mean by "not limited?" Do you mean unbounded?

To answer this, what is the definition of convergence you are using? You need a proof by contradiction. Can you start the proof?

Comment: First of all what I wrote was literally the question on the paper, if the question was clear why would you think that I would ask. second of all I never asked for the answers but for explanation so I can understand how to answer the question myself.  And seriously if you don't feel like explaining you could have just ignored the question.

Comment: If you follow the suggestions in my answer you will see that I give sufficient information for you to solve the problem yourself. To respond to your other complaints: (1) It is important to examine and question the exercise to ensure you understand it. (2) My answer allows you to answer the question yourself. Please consider more constructive comments.